# elasticsearch.js: ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I'm trying to create a project using `elasticsearch.js`. I'm following the docs found [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/quick-start.html).

In the `<head>` I've loaded:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/elasticsearch.js"></script>
<script src="js/esInit.js"></script>
```

and in `custom.js` I have

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
    {Host Here}
});
```

In FB console I see

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined  
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
```

I'm reading that `require()` is not a function of `javascript`. Very confused.

Comment: did you need to load requirejs from here by chance? http://requirejs.org/

Comment: When I drop in require.js I get the following error: Error: Module name "elasticsearch" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([]) http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded

Comment: after using the link in the `cosole.error` and using the wrapper they recomened, I get another error saying `elasticsearch` is not defined.

Comment: Are you using the browser builds of the elasticsearch.js client?

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/browser-builds.html

Comment: https://github.com/elastic/bower-elasticsearch-js If you look at the repository.. require is not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are loading the version that is supposed to be used with Node.js.

There are browser compatible builds available as well: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/browser-builds.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes require is not a default function in javascript. Instead you need to download that js file from "http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html"